# Is actionbarsherlock a replacement of android support lib v7?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

If so, it seems  actionbarsherlock lack of class PopupMenu and so on

If not, I can't import both of the libraries in the same project. It says some attributes conflict.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not a replacement, in fact with the release of AppCompat in v7 ABS is now considered deprecated and you should use the standard google support library to use the actionbar.

the point of the ABS library was to have a way to show an actionbar on devices < 3.0 and now that you can with the support lib v7 it is not needed

Comment: Oh, thank you, I have just noticed that Google has offically supported ActionBar  in the last release in support-library-v7 last month.  http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not. ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the compatibility library designed to Facilitate the use of the **Action Bar** design pattern across all versions of Android. The Android Support Library package is a set of code libraries that provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs as well as features that are only available through the library APIs. Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level. This design means That your applications can use the libraries' features and still be compatible with devices running Android 1.6 (API level 4) and up.